# It is impossible to put $x = f(x)g(x)$, where $f$ and $g$ are differentiable Functions and $f(0) = g(0) = 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question that i don't understand and it  was mentioned in my textbook of calculus.

why It is impossible to put $x =f(x)g(x)$, where $f$ and $g$ are differentiable Functions and $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ ?

Some help please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x=f(x)g(x)$ then $1=f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)$.  If $f(0)=g(0)=0$ then you get $1=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Just take the derivative of both sides and see what happens at $x=0$.